# Find and eliminate duplicates in strings

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server 2012 table with a column of type `[varchar](max) NULL`.

It basically contains a list of email addresses separated by a semicolon

```
noone@anywhere.com; bob@company.com; noone@anywhere.com
```

Without going into a discussion about how it would be better to resolve the source data that came to create this situation (which is perfectly reasonable advice), is there any clever way to eliminate said duplicates?

```
bob@company.com; noone@anywhere.com
```

The only rules I have is that

- There will be a semicolon between addresses in the string
- But not at the start, and not at the end
- The column may also be NULL
- Sort order is irrelevant

Slicing and dicing substrings is fine, but I don't see how to do substitution in SQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are 2012, here is an XML approach

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,SomeCol varchar(500))
Insert Into @YourTable values
 (1,'noone@anywhere.com; bob@company.com; noone@anywhere.com')
,(2,'no@dupe.com')

Select A.ID
      ,B.NewValue
 From @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
               Select NewValue = stuff( ( Select Distinct '; ' +ltrim(rtrim(i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
                                            From  ( values (cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(SomeCol,';','§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.'))) A(x)
                                            Cross Apply x.nodes('x') X(i)
                                            For XML Path ('')),1, 2,'') 
             ) B
```

**Results**

```
ID  NewValue
1   bob@company.com; noone@anywhere.com
2   no@dupe.com
```

Comment: Thanks .. .that's a new one for me ... Cross Apply?

Comment: @Maxcot [docs?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#using-apply)

Comment: yep, I figured as much. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

As you have hinted in your question, it would be much better to *not* store CSV data like this in your table.  Assuming you are using SQL Server 2017 or later, you may use a combination of `STRING_SPLIT` and `STRING_AGG` here:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT LTRIM(value) AS value
    FROM yourTable
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(input, ';')
)

SELECT STRING_AGG(value, '; ') AS input
FROM cte;
```

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

By using pure XQuery's FLWOR expression and the`distinct-values()` function.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, emails VARCHAR(MAX))
INSERT INTO @tbl (emails) VALUES
('noone@anywhere.com; bob@company.com; noone@anywhere.com'),
('no@dupe.com');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @separator CHAR(1) = ';';

SELECT t.*
    , REPLACE(c.query('
        for $x in distinct-values(/root/r)
        return data($x)
    ').value('.','VARCHAR(MAX)'),SPACE(1),@separator) AS Result
FROM @tbl AS t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TRY_CAST('<root><r><![CDATA[' + 
      REPLACE(REPLACE(emails,SPACE(1),''), @separator, ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + 
      ']]></r></root>' AS XML)) AS t1(c);
```

**Output**

```
+----+---------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------+
| ID |                         emails                          |               Result               |
+----+---------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------+
|  1 | noone@anywhere.com; bob@company.com; noone@anywhere.com | bob@company.com;noone@anywhere.com |
|  2 | no@dupe.com                                             | no@dupe.com                        |
+----+---------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------+
```